# Angular5CSV formatting directly with a delimiter in excel?

Tags: angular, angular-material, export-to-csv, delimiter, angular-material-table

I've been using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-csv to export my material data table to CSV format. I used the ',' field seperator but in excel you actually have to convert data using the delimiter, and **I would like to know if it's possible to directly have the formatted csv.**

Here's my code.

```
exportCsv() {
    let options = {
      fieldSeparator: ',',
      showLabels: true,
      useBom: true,
      headers: ['Name', 'Errors'],
      nullToEmptyString: true
    };
    new Angular5Csv(this.renderedData, 'Test Report', options);
}
```

If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think excel uses `;` as default separator for CSV files.

Comment: Thanks man that actually solves the problem :)